# AVRO schema for JSON with mixed record types

Tags: json, avro

I have the following problem, for which I kindly ask for your advice.
I have a JSON file where events of several types come mixed in the same file. Each event is a record with linear structure (no nesting). All events have an identifier and an event type, and depending on the event type, the structure of fields in the event record is different.
I need to make an AVRO schema file (.avsc), in order to be able to transform the JSON file into binary AVRO format.
Given a fragment of the JSON as below, can you please suggest me how to build the corresponding AVRO schema, please?

```
{"eventid":"EV1","eventtype":"A","timestamp": 1366150681, "fieldA1": 10, "fieldA2":"texta" }
{"eventid":"EV2","eventtype":"A","timestamp": 1366150699, "fieldA1": 11, "fieldA2":"atext" }
{"eventid":"EV3","eventtype":"B","timestamp": 1366150750, "fieldB1": "textb" }
{"eventid":"EV4","eventtype":"A","timestamp": 1366150821, "fieldA1": 9, "fieldA2":"texta" }
{"eventid":"EV5","eventtype":"C","timestamp": 1366150920, "fieldC1": 100, "fieldC2":200, "fieldC3":400 }
{"eventid":"EV6","eventtype":"C","timestamp": 1366150950, "fieldC1": 90, "fieldC2":150, "fieldC3":200 }
{"eventid":"EV7","eventtype":"B","timestamp": 1366150999, "fieldB1": "btext"}
```

and so on ...

Thank you very much in advance! I wait for your answer as soon as possible, please.